# ReplicaSet fails with invalid: spec.template.metadata.labels

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to do some research on replicaSet for my learning purpose. I was able to create a replicaSet successfully with matchLabels. To test the matchExpression selector, I created a pod first then a new replica set to test if the replica set will be able to check the labels from the running pods. But this failed with error. Here is what I did so far.

1. Created a pod first with a specific label. Pod runs successfully.
2. Create a replicaSet with matchExpressions matching the value with the label specified in the pod.

After the second step I get error. Below are the YAML files and the error.
Can you help me understand the issue here ?

Here is the pod-definition.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nginx-app
  labels:
    tier: frontend1

spec:
  containers:
  - name: nginx-c
    image: nginx
```

Here is the replicaset-definition.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: ReplicaSet
metadata:
  name: replicaset-2
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchExpressions:
      - {key: tier, operator: In, values: [frontend1]}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        tier: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx
```

Error while creating replica set:

> master $ kubectl create -f /root/replicaset-definition.yaml
>
> The ReplicaSet "replicaset-2" is invalid:
>   spec.template.metadata.labels: Invalid value:
>   map[string]string{"tier":"nginx"}: `selector` does not match template
>   `labels`

Comment: You can add `nginx` to your `values:` field, this way the pod will fall into RS control. Is that what you tried to achieve?

Comment: Thanks @KFC_ This works now, so the matchExpressions or matchLabels requires atleast one matching condition with the labels defined under template for the replicaSet to get created. I changed the `matchExpressions` to `{key: tier, operator: In, values: [frontend1, nginx]}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try with the following by changing the label in template section.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: ReplicaSet
metadata:
  name: replicaset-2
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchExpressions:
      - {key: tier, operator: In, values: [frontend1]}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        tier: frontend1
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx
```

Comment: Thanks Dinesh. I just edited my question to be more clear of my requirement. I want to check if replicaSet will be able to matchExpressions of the running pods that are not defined in the template section.

Comment: In kubernetes documentation, it is clearly mention that In the ReplicaSet, .spec.template.metadata.labels must match spec.selector, or it will be rejected by the API. https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/replicaset/

Answer (score 0):

To make pod fall into newly created ReplicaSet's scope using `matchExpressions` you have to either use the same labels in RS as defined in already created pod or you have to add additional label in the expression so it looks like following:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: ReplicaSet
metadata:
  name: replicaset-2
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchExpressions:
    - key: tier
      operator: In
      values:
      - frontend1
      - nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        tier: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx
```

This way RS will recognize already existing pod as its own and create only one more pod to meet the requirements defined in `replicas` field.